# Jsoup parseBodyFragment excludes elements having style attribute display:none

Tags: java, jsoup

I use Jsoup's `parseBodyFragment` method to convert a Java string to a Jsoup `Document` object:

```
String trElem  =  "<tr>"
               +  "  <td data-column-name='ID' style='display:none;'></td>"
               +  "  <td data-column-name='Name'><input type='text' value='Jones'></td>"
               +  "</tr>" ;
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(trElem) ;
System.out.println ( "\nJsoup doc is " + doc + "\n" ) ;
```

However, the first <td> element is excluded from the `Document` object returned by `parseBodyFragment`, as shown below (the output of my `System.out.println`):

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" value="Jones" />
  </body>
</html>
```

My question: how can I include all elements (both those with `display:none` and those without) in the object returned by parseBodyFragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup is trying to normalize the html that parses. In this case it doesn't see any  tags so it ignores completely the <tr> and <td> tags. There are two options

1. Add the <table></table> tags
2. Use this `Document doc = Jsoup.parse(trElem, "", Parser.xmlParser());`

Comment: I tried option # 1 (above), and it worked just fine.  Thank you.